# Having trouble with the syntax of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouse-coordinates

```
fill(225, 0, 225);
var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 12, 12); 
    var label = mouseX + "36", "45" + mouseY;
    text(label, mouseX, mouseY);
};
```

I'm creating a small mouse tracker program that calls the coordinates of the mouse pointer just below and to the right of a small circle, using Khan Academy, it's one of their challenges. In particular I'm getting errors when creating the string where I'm attempting to store mouseX and Y along with some coordinates in to the variable 'label'.

Comment: Can you post the error you get in the console?

Comment: What are you wanting your label value to be?  mouseX value + 36 then a ',' then mouseY value + 45?  so something like "XValue,YValue"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var label = mouseX + "36", "45" + mouseY;
```

You have some funky syntax there, that's not a proper way to use a comma when creating strings.  It's not obvious what you really want, but I'm betting something like this:

```
var label = "mouseX:" + mouseX + ", mouseY" + mouseY;
```

Which would save a string like `"mouseX:123, mouseY:456"` to the var `label`.

Comment: Thank you Alex, that was what I was looking for. Just to be clear with what's happening there, is it saying, I'm making the variable label and in it I'm storing mouseX as text plus mouseX as a value plus mouseX as text plus mouseY the value, value being a variable in this case. I'm I thinking about this right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got it to work!

fill(255, 0, 255);

```
var draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 12, 12);
    var label = mouseX + " , " + mouseY;
    text(label, mouseX, mouseY);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need var next to the draw = function(), and instead of putting the numbers in the quotes, put a space between the quotes, also make the label variable outside of the draw function, so that your code looks like this :

```
var label;
draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    fill(225, 0, 225);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 12, 12); 
    label = "    " + mouseX + "   " + mouseY;
    fill(0,0,0);
    text(label, mouseX, mouseY);
};
```